# make sure elements in li remove class when another is clicked

Tags: jquery, click, parent

I've got some basic markup for the example

```
<ul class="foo">
    <li class="baz is-closed"><p class="bar">John</p></li>
    <li class="baz is-closed"><p class="bar">Paul</p></li>
    <li class="baz is-closed"><p class="bar">George</p></li>
    <li class="baz is-closed"><p class="bar">Ringo</p></li>
</ul>
```

And then I've got this jquery to affect the parent class on click -

```
$('.bar').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('is-open');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('is-closed');
    return false;
});
```

What I want is when someone 'clicks' John (the parent li changes to is-open) then 'clicks' Paul I want Johns parent to replace is-open with is-closed.

Possible?

Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just select the `.is-open` class on click and replace it with `.is-closed`?

```
$('.foo .is-open').removeClass('is-open').addClass('is-closed');
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G86Zq/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('.bar').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('is-open').siblings().removeClass('is-closed');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can close all `<li>`, then open the clicked one:

```
$('.bar').click(function() {
     $('.baz').toggleClass('is-closed');
     $(this).parent().toggleClass('is-open');
    return false;  
});
```

Hope i've understood that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.bar').click(function() {
    $('.foo li').removeClass('is-open').addClass('is-closed');
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('is-open is-closed');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MNqUx/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
    $('li.baz')
        .removeClass('is-open')
        .addClass('is-closed');

    $(this)
        .removeClass('is-closed')
        .addClass('is-open');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YkZqj/17/